# how to import com.google.api.client libraries?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, import, google-api-java-client

This question might be asked before but I couldn't solve my problem with those explananations.
I want to start using google apis in my Eclipse IDE. I've downloaded a sample from google codes. (latitude-json-oauth-sample). It requires to import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth. From where I can find and how import those to this project?
I've installed maven and mylyn plugins, and I thought that with these plugins I would be able to download all dependencies but I couldn't make it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artifacts are available in the central maven repository. Add following to your pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client-auth</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3-alpha</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Kees, After adding this to pom file, what should I exactly do to run the project?

Comment: `mvn clean compile` on the command line; in Eclipse "Maven / Update dependencies"